# Indentation comments algorithm2e

Tags: indentation, algorithm2e

I am trying to use `algorithm2e` for my pseudocode. I am having a weird behavior with the comments.

1. I want them to appear right after the code, on the right, while there seems to be a random (quite big) space that I don't want.
2. sometimes I tried to have comments on a line, which means that they don't come right after a piece of pseudocode, but I start directly with the comment itself. This was giving me error, any way to achieve this?

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\KwData{Number of samples per pixel N, image and camera properties}
\KwResult{Path Traced image $I_i$, and Gradient Domain Path Traced $\Delta_{i,j}$}
\For{each pixel \emph{i} of the image }{
\For{each sample per pixel}{
$I_i = I_i + h(x-x_i)f(\bar{x})/p(\bar{x})$\tcp*{\textbf{add contribution of base path to the primal image}}
$I_i = I_i/N; $\\
\For{all neighbour pixels $ j \in \Phi_i  of  i$ }{
$\bar{y} := T_{ij}(\bar{x})$\tcp*{\textbf{calculate offset path with shift mapping}}
$\Delta_{i,j} := \Delta_{i,j} + w_{i,j}(\bar{x})h(x-x_i)(f(\bar{x}) - f(\bar{y})|T_{ij}|);$\\
$\Delta_{i,j} := Delta_{i,j} /N $  \tcp*{\textbf{for all \emph{j}}}
} 
}
}
\caption{How to compute GDPT}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an optional argument you can supply to `\tcp` that updates the way it displays in terms of the alignment. For more details, see section **10.3 comments** (p 32) of the [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf).

Below I've used `[h]` and `[l]` to have a left-aligned comment without/with a line-end.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e,mathtools}
\newcommand{\ce}{\coloneqq}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \KwData{Number of samples per pixel $N$, image and camera properties}
  \KwResult{Path Traced image $I_i$, and Gradient Domain Path Traced $\Delta_{i,j}$}
  \For{each pixel\/ $i$ of the image }{
    \For{each sample per pixel}{
      \tcp*[h]{\textbf{add contribution of base path to the primal image}}
      $I_i = I_i + h(x-x_i)f(\bar{x})/p(\bar{x})$\;
      $I_i = I_i/N$\;
      \For{all neighbour pixels\/ $j \in \Phi_i$ of\/ $i$}{
        \tcp*[h]{\textbf{calculate offset path with shift mapping}}
        $\bar{y} \ce T_{ij}(\bar{x})$\;
        $\Delta_{i,j} \ce \Delta_{i,j} + w_{i,j}(\bar{x})h(x-x_i)(f(\bar{x}) - f(\bar{y})|T_{ij}|)$\;
        $\Delta_{i,j} \ce Delta_{i,j} /N$\tcp*[l]{\textbf{for all $j$}}
      } 
    }
  }
  \caption{How to compute GDPT}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much! it's exactly what I was looking for!